# What librairies exists to create "moving/living" UI in delphi?

Tags: delphi, user-interface

While reading delphifeeds yesterday I discovered [delQuery](http://bitbucket.org/utku/delquery/wiki/Home), which allows one to get some nice animation on his form very simply.

I would like to know if there are any other libraries of that kind out there and what experience you had with them ?

(I'm trying to find a way to make my application more alive in terms of GUI; buttons that grow when you hover them, that kind of animations but with a nice programmatic interface)

Comment: Wow, thats cool.  Why cant you just use delQuery?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Do you mean something like [Billenium Effects](http://www.billeniumsoft.com/bef/index.htm)?

[image]
<sub>(source: [billeniumsoft.com](http://www.billeniumsoft.com/bef/images/Rollb.gif))</sub>

Answer (score 0):

There is CrossGL at http://www.crossgl.com/

Comment: CrossGL appears to be an in-house tool not available to the general public.